# Add empty section to NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am making a view just like the iPhone Calendar ListView. I am using core data and getting appointments and grouping them by date.

However just like in the iPhone listview I need to add a blank section for today even if there are no appointments. I cannot figure out how to do this for a section with no appointments since I am doing the sorting before I create the grouping.

How would I add an empty section to the `NSFetchedResultsController` and have it resorted so that today's date is in the correct spot and not at the end of the list?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Appointments" inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Sort using the date / then time property.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorTime = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_time" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorDate, sortDescriptorTime, nil];


    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Use the sectionIdentifier property to group into sections.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have empty sections with `NSFetchedResultsController` - that's just the way it is designed at the moment, and I would call it a limitation :)

This problem has been encountered and addressed by a Timothy Armes who has created a class `TAFetchedResultsController`, which allows for empty sections. It's a replacement for `NSFetchedResultsController`. It also allows you to sort your sections on fields which aren't the section name (quite handy)

However, you will need to make changes to your Core Data model - it's not quite a drop in replacement.

https://github.com/timothyarmes/TAFetchedResultsController

But it does work well, and will solve your problem if you are willing to re-do your data model.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am not sure how this can help me. Since I am creating the sections based on the date object for the item, I am not sure how I could implement this without changing my whole scheme. Using this looks like I would need the items and sections sent in separately.

Comment: OK - I've updated my answer to be more concise. The fact is, you can't have an empty section with `NSFetchedResultsController` - bad news I'm afraid. However, it shouldn't take too much to re-jig your data model to allow you to use the `TAFetchedResultsController` class. You then would just need to create section objects for each day (1 through 31 I would presume) and create a relationship to your appointment objects. Tim has got example code on there which is easy to follow. I think you will be able to achieve what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am currently struggling with an `NSFetchedResultsController` that returns an empty section. It says it has one section, but there are 0 objects in it. So this behaviour may have changed.